# How to route application with two same path ='' in angular 4

Tags: angular, path, routes

I am not finding any way to navigate my application according to user access.

every time it is hitting first path = '' in routing.ts file.

I want to route my application with two path = '' , as according to access some time i want it to go on first path , sometime another.

Comment: can you be please a bit clearer? The question is unintelligible in it's current state. Also please try to provide code, what you want to do, and what is your exact problem.

Answer (score -1):

For me it's clear enought, please take a look this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfirad?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: { path: "", redirectTo: "/lazy/main", pathMatch: "full" } What is i write the line again , with another redirect?